# Странное поведение curl -H 'Host: google.ru' http://SITE.RU

Tags: apache, curl

Добрый день.

Заметил странное поведение при попытке обратиться к домену на сервере через curl с подменой host.
При вводе команды `curl -H 'Host: google.ru' http://SITE.RU` выдаётся содержимое первого сайта, размещенного по IP SITE.RU на сервере, а не содержимое запрашиваемого сайта.

В чём может быть проблема? Или это так и должно быть?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае, сервер `site.ru` настроен так, что заголовок `Host` просто игнорируется, когда его значение не известно. В большинстве случаев это нормально.

Вообще, в случае если заголовок `Host` не обслуживается сервером, сервер может отдать:

```
406 Not acceptable
```

Так, например, делает `yandex.ru`.

При работе с утилитой `curl` есть одна хитрость: ключ `-v`. Он позволяет видеть, что именно происходит. Попробуйте:

```
curl -v -H 'Host: google.ru' http://SITE.RU
```

и

```
curl -v -H 'Host: google.ru' http://yandex.ru
```

Answer (score 0):

Так и должно быть.

Если на сервере нет сайта с прописанным host name "google.ru" - то отдается сайт по умолчанию - тот же, что при заходе по IP.